# What is the proper way to "placement new" an array of structs/classes with a generic member variable?

Tags: c++, placement-new

Given the following class:

```
template<class T, std::size_t N>
class Example {
    struct Element {
        std::size_t id;
        std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T), alignof(T)> actual_data;
    };
    std::array<Element, N> data;

public:
    template<typename ...Args>
    void emplace_insert(Args&&... args) {
        auto some_id = 123; //for example

        //placment new 
        new (&data[some_id]) Element(some_id, T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    }
};
```

How would I go about using the placement new on data in the `emplace_insert` function? Do I need to define a custom constructor for the `Element` struct, and if so, how would I go about passing the arguments for the  `aligned_storage_t`?

I'm using the aligned storage to prevent default construction.

Now for the final question, I realize this one might be more opinion based, but I'm still hoping I could get some sort of answer.

Would it be better to just maintain a 2nd array that contains the id rather than trying to combine the two?

Comment: Wouldn't you just do `data[some_id].id = some_id; new (&data[some_id].actual_data) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);`?

Comment: @melpomene Now that I think about it, that does make sense, because the array of Elements is default constructed after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `data` is an array, and the `Element`s themselves are properly initialized. It is `actual_data` that you should use placement new on.

```
data[some_id].id = some_id;
new (&data[some_id].actual_data) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
```

That said, why do you maintain `id` in the element? It is already taken care of by `std::array`.

Comment: in  this case, the data structure I'm making needs to be able to find the index of the element from the element, I'm not sure of any other way to go about doing that

Comment: @HexCrown OK. That's just a side comment and don't take it seriously.

Comment: For more clarification, the insert method will return an id, that id wont be the true elements id, rather it will be an id to a lookup array that will check the real index. what im going to be doing is shuffling the elements internally while allowing a constant index from the outside.